# Confusion Regarding Constructor Chaining in Java

Tags: java, constructor, constructor-chaining

From what I understand about Constructor Chaining is that

> Whenever we create an object of child class (or call child class constructor) a 
>    call to default constructor of parent class is automatically made first *ONLY IF*
>    our child constructor does not happen to call another constructor either using *this* (for same class) or *super* keyword. source: http://www.java67.com/2012/12/how-constructor-chaining-works-in-java.html

So if my understanding is correct

Then for the following code:-

```
Class First{
    First(){
    System.out.print("Hello");
    }

Class Second extends First{

    Second(int i)
    {
    System.out.println("Blogger");
    }
    Second(){
    this(2);    //default constructor is calling another constructor using this keyword
    }


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Second ob = new Second();
}
```

Output should be `Blogger` only.

But the output is `HelloBlogger`

So it seems the default constructor of parent class is still being called indeed.
But quoting from that source:-

> 2) If you do not call another constructor either from parent class or same class than Java calls default or no argument constructor of super class.

Read more: http://www.java67.com/2012/12/how-constructor-chaining-works-in-java.html#ixzz4qztuMrKW

So please help out!

Comment: `super` is ALWAYS implicitly called first. Yes, if you call `this`, it will call another constructor without calling `super` in the CURRENT constructor, but `super` will be inserted as the first call automatically in THAT constructor. It doesn't make sense for it to *not* call `super`.

Comment: @Tal Sorry was editing it only.

Comment: The point is that the rule in question is applied to **every** constructor. It's applied to Second() and it's applied to Second(int). This way everything becomes clear.

Comment: @AndrewLi  `super` could be of any form doesn't have to be default right? Also so my understanding is wrong right?

Comment: It is not called when you use `this()` because it refers to another constructor that will (or not) implicitly call `super()`, it's just a constructor chain until you call one which doesn't call `this()`

Comment: That clears things up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic rule is that one way or another a superclass constructor is **always** called. There is no trick out of this rule* and for good reason: the subclass relies on the state of the superclass, so if the superclass is not initialised, the subclass behaviour is incorrect. (Think of inherited `protected` fields for example.)

If you add an explicit call to `super(...)` (you can choose which super constructor to call here), then that will be called, otherwise `super()` (with no arguments) will be called implicitly from any constructor that doesn't call another using `this(...)`.

In your case the chain is as follows: `Second() -> Second(int) -> First()`. The first call is explicit (`this(2)`), the second is implicit.

*For nitpickers, this statement is obviously not true if you use deserialisation or `Unsafe`. :)

Comment: Oh I get it, So it is actually the Second(int) constructor from the Child class that happens to call the Parent class constructor. And this is how Constructor Chaining is taking place. Hence the name!!  I fully understand now! :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the default constructor only calls `this(int)`, but `this(int)` implicitly calls `super()`. It's impossible to make a constructor that doesn't *eventually* call some form of `super()`.

Comment: Some form of super() or you mean just the default constructor super()?

Comment: @Shad In your example, it'll call the default `super()`. But if the superclass doesn't have a no-arg constructor, you'll have to call it explicitly so you can specify the arguments.